# Objective C removeAllObjects NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have a mutable array:

```
NSMutableArray *locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

When I call a IBAction (which could be called 1000 times if the user kept pressing it i guess) it places pins on a map, stored in that array.

I have called this after creating the array:

```
[locations removeAllObjects]
```

However the pins still appear on top of each other, has this cleared the array correctly?

Comment: The syntax is not hard, nor is it the most confusing part of the language. The problem is that you most likely didn't remove the pins from the map itself.

Comment: recall annotation (pin) method after get new array

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Ahh I didnt think about that! I will try find the code to remove it

Comment: remove annotations from mapview.

Comment: add your code here. removing from array is not enough. you need to remove annotations from map also.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, I will update answer I can't seem to delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)removeAllAnnotations {

    NSMutableArray *annotationsToRemove = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.map.annotations count]];
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.map.annotations count]; i++) {

            [annotationsToRemove addObject:[self.map.annotations objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    [self.map removeAnnotations:annotationsToRemove];
}
```

Comment: This unforunately doesn't answer the question asked. The OP has not specified whether or not he is in fact using a map view, or what kind of map view he's using, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and apologies for the very vague question. I appreciate the time everyone has taken and the ball ache it has caused. I hope you can understand that it is difficult for me at this time, as this is pretty much my first week in Objective C

Answer (score 1):

add the following line of code under the "removeAllObjects" line

```
[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];
```

Comment: This unforunately doesn't answer the question asked. The OP has not specified whether or not he is in fact using a map view, or what kind of map view he's using, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: dude hav you read the question.. read it.. it has a line " it places pins on a map".. keep your eyes open..

Answer (score 0):

This is not due to clearance of objects in the array. You have to remove annotions from the mapView by calling

[mapViewObjectName removeAnnotions: locations];

Then all annotations that you allocated in the location array will be removed.

Thank You

Comment: This unforunately doesn't answer the question asked. The OP has not specified whether or not he is in fact using a map view, or what kind of map view he's using, so this doesn't answer the question.